# how do you use a variable when giving the source of an image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

if i type this:

```
test.innerHTML += "<img src=./images/pink.JPG>"+"<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'></label>";
```

i am able to display the image pink. However how would i do this by using a variable
i.e picture = "pink.JPG"

i have tried

```
test.innerHTML += "<img src=./images/' + picture + '>"+"<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'></label>";
```

however it doesn't work. What would be the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

We use `back-ticks` now **`** in ES6. If you use these you no longer need to worry about anything else. Just try this:

```
test.innerHTML += `<img src="./images/pink.JPG"><label><input type="radio" name="choices" value="A"></label>`;
```

This will also help in using a dynamic data or url being added in your code (String Interpolation) using `${srcUrl}` This is freaking easy to use as well.

Comment: @Bea: Hope this is the best and easy approach so far. You can learn more about this from ES6 string interpolation topic. Do please rate and accept  my answer for other's to benefit from this as well. Thank you mate :)

Answer (score 0):

The key is using the same quotes that you are wrapping the string with, in this case it is double quotes.

```
test.innerHTML += "<img src='./images/" + picture + "'><label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'></label>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `"` instead of `'`
So your code wood look like this:

```js
test.innerHTML += "<img src=\"./images/" + picture + "\">"+"<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'></label>"
```

And if you still want to use `"` for "hugging" an attribute, you can use `\"`